# Is it Possible to Automatically Define Functions in Lua

Tags: function, for-loop, automation, lua, neovim

These are some functions I want to define:

```lua
local function nmap(lhs, rhs, opts)
    keymap.set("n", lhs, rhs, opts)
end

local function imap(lhs, rhs, opts)
    keymap.set("i", lhs, rhs, opts)
end

local function vmap(lhs, rhs, opts)
    keymap.set("v", lhs, rhs, opts)
end

local function cmap(lhs, rhs, opts)
    keymap.set("c", lhs, rhs, opts)
end

local function omap(lhs, rhs, opts)
    keymap.set("o", lhs, rhs, opts)
end
```

It is repetitive though. Is there a more efficient way to define these functions? The only thing that is different in each of these functions is one letter (n, i, v, c, o). Can I use a for loop to automatically define each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using _G (the global environment table) you can do that.

```lua
local letters = {'n', 'i', 'v', 'c', 'o'}

for _, c in ipairs(letters) do
    _G[c..'map'] = function(...)
        keymap.set(c, ...)
    end
end

-- cmap(insert, arguments, here)
```

This is actually stated under this guide as well
https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide
*See the `The vim namespace` section*

---

*Just be careful not to override any important variables (like the table or math library haha) :)*

Comment: Also just before any Roblox lua devs try this, no it doesn't work in Roblox scripts since Roblox Lua is different

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me, even after copying your solution word-for-word. It game the error "attempt to call global ..." meaning the function does not exist. It also doesn't work in a regular Lua script outside of Neovim. I am using Neovim's latest release: 0.7.2 as of now.

Comment: whoops my bad, it should be `for _, c in ipairs` in order to get the character! @Amarakon try now :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. `pairs` as opposed to `ipairs` also works.

Comment: What part of Roblox Lua is different that would make this not work there? Is `_G` not available?

Comment: `_G` does not point to the global environment in Roblox Lua. It’s just a global table that’s shared between scripts. (This is afaik for security reasons) in addition Roblox has another global table `shared` it’s awkward to say the least lol @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica